# Terraform tfstate s3 not creating

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to set up remote backend for my terraform workflow. My backend block is as follows

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-aws-007"
    key    = "global/bananadev/s3/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-2"
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB8xt.png)
Terraform initialization is successful, however the state file is not being created in my s3 bucket but locally.

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: What makes you think its creating the state file locally?

Comment: Also, if nothing is applied there will be no state file created.

Comment: after initialization, state file cannot be created. Run terraform apply, then you can see what is happening

Comment: Terraform plan and apply works

Comment: I can see the state file in .terraform directory. It should be in the s3 bucket